# Create a Customer Community User in Test to Login Connected Application

Tags: community, user, customer-community, connected-apps, login

Please help out in any way possible with the below challenge;

We have an application connected to salesforce which is logged in by our customers(accounts) through community users which are created for their accounts.

These community users are created through the class: "site.createExternalUser(user, accountId, password)" when the customer registers himself on the application from the app interface.

However, now we are trying to create some test customer community users to test a few things. I tried using site.createExternalUser but it did not work.
If someone can help me with this, let me know.

OR

Secondly, I am trying to directly create the customer community users through an apex class and the user is created but I do not know how to setup the "PASSWORD" for these users using the code. I mean when I try to login my app, what would be the password to login?
My code to create a new contact+user & then assign them to an account is below and the contact+user are created successfully but I am unable to login the app (most probably because I do not have a password)

```
public class createUsersv4 {


    public user createPartnerUser(){  

        Account a = [select name from Account where Id='0010Q00000DO8b7QAD'];
       // system.debug('Account = ' + a.Name);

        Contact c = New Contact(LastName = 'Test', AccountID = a.id);
        insert c;
       // system.debug('Contact = ' + c.Id);

        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Customer Community user' LIMIT 1];

        user u = New User(
            UserName = 'test_' + math.random() + '@test.com',
            FirstName = 'Test-First',
            LastName = 'Test-Last',
            Alias = 'test',
            email = 'test' + math.random() + '@test.com',
            CommunityNickName = string.valueOf(math.random()).substring(0,6),
            ProfileID = p.id,
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York', 
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            ContactID = c.Id

            );

        system.debug('User = ' + u.Id);

        insert u;

        return u;


    }

}
```

Comment: Right now because you are not setting the password, is your problem. What is your use case here, do you want to set the password within your apex code as well? If yes, then there's another method available for this purpose -- `createExternalUser(user, accountId, password)` that you can use.

Comment: @JayantDas, the problem is that I am unable to create a user using this method, I have tried a lot but the userID keeps showing 'null' or sometimes it gives me an error that this function needs to be called from a form to work. If you have some boilerplate working code for creating users in this way, I will be really obliged. In fact, this method would be my first priority if it could be successfully done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just hard coding the user's password for testing ONLY you could, after the user is inserted add another line as below:

```
insert u;
System.setPassword(u.Id, 'yourpasswordhere');
return u;
```